# pulling image from a docker hub repository, what is the proper url to use

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, dockerhub

I have published an image on docker hub (private repository) and it looks like this

```
myname/repo-name:1442058646
```

I'm trying to deploy this on a GKE (autopilot cluster, and public no private) using the following

```
docker.io/myname/repo-name:1442058646
```

However, when deploying I get an error from GKE saying unable to pull image.  I am able to pull this same image from my local machine without logging into docker hub.  Any help anyone ?  Am I using the proper url ?

Comment: Don't you think you should expect to auth to a private repo?  Likely is already configured locally.   Regardless,  we found gcr the path of least resistance for private images deployed to gke.

Comment: It does not require auth so it should work.  The reason I'm not considering gcr is because of the cost, I'm on the free tier.

Comment: you were correct, I had created a private repository hence it was not pulling, but when I made it public, it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/):

> You need to be signed in and have access to work with a private repository.

For private images you must create a secret with the username and password of Docker Hub to Kubernetes be able to pull the image.

Also as suggested by @Daniel Farrell since you have created a private repository hence it was not pulling, switching  it to public will work .

Refer to the documentation on [Pulling an image from a private registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).